# css text animation not centered on page

Tags: animation, css-animations, center

I have been having issues centering the text animation on my page, it does not center correctly on all viewports, I have been messing with the keyframes changing them from left: 130px to sometimes 150px to get it centered but it isn't centered properly, that doesn't seem to help, I have also taken off animation-fill mode: forwards, and it seems to just glitch in the middle of the page instead of being a smooth transition. Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

```js
tsParticles.load("tsparticles", {
    fps_limit: 60,
    interactivity: {
      detect_on: "canvas",
      events: {
        onclick: { enable: true, mode: "push" },
        onhover: {
          enable: true,
          mode: "attract",
          parallax: { enable: false, force: 60, smooth: 10 }
        },
        resize: true
      },
      modes: {
        push: { quantity: 4 },
        attract: { distance: 200, duration: 0.4, factor: 5 }
      }
    },
    particles: {
      color: { value: "#ffffff" },
      line_linked: {
        color: "#ffffff",
        distance: 150,
        enable: true,
        opacity: 0.4,
        width: 1
      },
      move: {
        attract: { enable: false, rotateX: 600, rotateY: 1200 },
        bounce: false,
        direction: "none",
        enable: true,
        out_mode: "out",
        random: false,
        speed: 2,
        straight: false
      },
      number: { density: { enable: true, value_area: 800 }, value: 80 },
      opacity: {
        anim: { enable: false, opacity_min: 0.1, speed: 1, sync: false },
        random: false,
        value: 0.5
      },
      shape: {
        character: {
          fill: false,
          font: "Verdana",
          style: "",
          value: "*",
          weight: "400"
        },
        image: {
          height: 100,
          replace_color: true,
          src: "images/github.svg",
          width: 100
        },
        polygon: { nb_sides: 5 },
        stroke: { color: "#000000", width: 0 },
        type: "circle"
      },
      size: {
        anim: { enable: false, size_min: 0.1, speed: 40, sync: false },
        random: true,
        value: 5
      }
    },
    polygon: {
      draw: { enable: false, lineColor: "#ffffff", lineWidth: 0.5 },
      move: { radius: 10 },
      scale: 1,
      type: "none",
      url: ""
    },
    retina_detect: true
  });

  const intro = document.querySelector("#intro")


  

  // intro.style.display = "none";

//  const timeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 2000)



// window.onload(function () {
//   intro.style.display = "block";
// }
// )

//  const myGreeting = () => {
//    document.querySelector("#intro").textContent = "Hello Im";
  
//    }

//  const timeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 3000)

const secondGreeting = () => {
    document.querySelector(".name").textContent = "Peter Ayad"
}

const timeout2 = setTimeout(secondGreeting, 2500)

const button = document.querySelector('button');

//back to top button
const topButton = document.querySelector('.bTop')
// const divButton = document.querySelector('.divButton');

// divButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
//   document.body.scrollTop = 0;
//   document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
// })

// topButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
//   document.body.scrollTop = 0;
//   document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
// })
// // divButton.addEventListener('click', topFunction)
//  window.onscroll = function() {
//   topFunction();
//  }

window.onscroll = function() {
    topFunction();
   }
  

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

topButton = document.querySelector(".bTop");
```

```css
html {
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    /* vertical-align: bottom; */
  }

/* ---- tsparticles container ---- */
#tsparticles {
    position: absolute;
    /* position: fixed; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0d47a1;
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    /* background-position: 50% 50%; */
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .github {
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 12px 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  
  .github a:hover,
  .github a:link,
  .github a:visited,
  .github a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .github img {
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .github #gh-project {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }

  .bg-img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

#bgCanvas {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    offset-position: center;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* span#intro {
    margin-top: 40%;
    color: white;
} */

.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* margin-top: 50%; */
}

.introParagraph {
    display: inline-block;
    position : relative;
}

p {
    /* margin-top: 0; */
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    color: white;
}

form {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

/* span#intro {
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
animation: appear 2s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
margin-top: 35%;
margin-left: 15%;
} */

p#intro {
    color: white;
    /* position: absolute; */
    position: fixed;
    animation: appear 2s;
    /* animation-fill-mode: forwards; */
    margin-top: 35%;
    /* color: white; */
    /* right: 0; */
}

.name {
    margin-left: 39%;
    color: white;
}

/* span#intro styles */
@keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
      
    }
    to {
        left: 140px;
        /* left: 30.5%; */
        /* text-align: center; */

    }
}

@-moz-keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 140px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 140px;
    }

}

@-o-keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 140px;
    }
}

.name {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    /* position: absolute; */
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 48%;
    /* margin-left: 43%; */
}

/* span#intro,
.name,
p {
    color: #ffffff;
} */

button {
    margin-top: 10%;
    /* background-color: initial; */
    /* background-color: white; */
    border: 2px solid black;
    animation: button 2s;
    /* padding: 10px; */
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

#divButton {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes button {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    15% {
        transform:translateY(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/* MEDIA QUERY 720PX */

@media (min-width: 720px) {
    span#intro {
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 20%;
        margin-left: 25%;
    }

    .name {
        /* font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute; */
        margin-top: 32%;
        margin-left: 40%;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    p.introParagraph {
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-top: 40%;
    }

    form {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

/* MEDIA QUERY 1024px */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    span#intro {
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0;
        /* margin-top: 20%;
        margin-left: 25%; */
        margin: 15% 31.5%;
    }

    .name {
        /* margin-top: 35%; */
        margin: 25% 43%
    }

    p.introParagraph {
        margin-top: 34%;
    }

    button {
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css"> -->
    <!-- <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Dancing+Script&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css">
    <title>New Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header1">
        <!-- <canvas id="bgCanvas"></canvas> -->
        <!-- <video>
            <source src="video/153868659.mp4" type="video/mp4" loop autoplay preload="auto">
        </video> -->

        <!-- <h4 class="name">Peter Ayad</h4> -->

        <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md"> -->

            <!-- <div class="nav_toggle" id="nav-toggle"> -->

                <!-- <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Peter Ayad</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks"> -->

                    <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks"></div> -->
                <!-- <ul class="nav_menu" id="nav-menu"> -->

                    <!-- <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Resume</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul> -->
            <!-- </div> -->

            <!-- <i class="bx bxs-grid"> -->
                <!-- <i class="bx bxs-grid" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></i> -->
        <!-- </nav> -->
        <!-- <h1 class="mainHeader">Welcome to Peter's Portfolio</h1> -->
    </header>

    <!-- <canvas id="bgCanvas"></canvas> -->

    <!-- Courtesy of CodePen/Vincent Garreau  -->
    <!-- <p class="codepen" data-height="300" data-default-tab="html,result" data-slug-hash="bGxvQd" data-user="VincentGarreau" style="height: 300px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;">
        <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/bGxvQd">
        particles.js</a> by Vincent Garreau (<a href="https://codepen.io/VincentGarreau">@VincentGarreau</a>)
        on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
      </p>
      <script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>-->

<!-- Courtesy of CodePen/Vincent Garreau  -->
      <div id="tsparticles"></div>


    <section class="mainSection">
    <div class="mainPage">

        <div class="flex">
            <!-- <span id="intro">Hello Im...</span> -->
            <p id="intro">Hello Im...</p>
           <!-- <div><span class="name">Peter Ayad</span></div> -->
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="name"></span>
        </div>
        <p class="introParagraph">
            <!-- Peter is a fullstck web developer and react designer. Emmerisve and beautiful websites and apps is his passion. -->
           A web developer that is passionate about <span class="create">creating</span> and designing <strong>beautiful</strong>, <span class="immersive">immersive</span>, and <em>interactive</em> websites.
        </p>

        <!-- <p>Interested in working together? Want to know more about what I do? check out my projects below!</p> -->
        <!-- <p>Check out my work</p> -->
        <form action="projects.html">
        <button id="divButton">Check out my work >></button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </section>

    
    <script async="" defer="" src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tsparticles@1.37.4/tsparticles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what your doing, but you could probably benefit from using `calc()`

Comment: Hey @ITDW srry i am trying to have the "Hello Im.." text in my p#intro element to shift from left to right at the center of the page, I have been messing with the keyframes, but its not adjusting center on all the viewports {320px, 720px, 1024px}. if I take it off position: absolute it becomes center but the animation no longer works. Is there a way around this maybe with (translateY), not sure, I appreciate your help.